# Installation from source in XUbuntu 12.10 with urdf

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to install gazebo 1.4 on my Xubuntu 12.10 from source code

analyzing the output of "cmake .." I've noticed that URDF module can not be recognized, altough I've added the ros groovy repository to my system.

In particular, I've done the following things:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu quantal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list./ros-latest.list'
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-urdfdom ros-groovy-urdfdom-headers
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-urdf ros-groovy-urdf-interface ros-groovy-urdf-parser
```

and then I've run

```
cmake ..
```

and also tried

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/ cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/share ..
```

I always obtain that the urdf modules are not found, altought they are installed

moreover, if I disable the "QUIT" flag in the find_package commands of SearchFroStuff.cmake I obtain the next warning:

```
checking for module 'urdfdom_headers'
package 'urdfdom_headers' not found
urdfdom_headers not found, urdf parser will not be built.
CMake Warning at cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:258 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /opt/ros/groovy/share/urdfdom/cmake/urdfdomConfig.cmake

  but it set urdfdom_FOUND to FALSE so package "urdfdom" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:142 (include)
```

(I obtain a similar output for `urdfdom_headers` and `console_bridge`

any suggestion?

thanks in advance
SImone

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1330/installation-from-source-in-xubuntu-12.10-with-urdf/) by [SImone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/207/simone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The recommended way to build Gazebo (< 1.9.0) with URDF support is to source the ROS setup file, e.g.:

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh
cmake ..
```

I just tested that sequence with ROS Groovy and Gazebo 1.4.0 and it was able to find the URDF libraries.

But then I tried your, more minimal, approach, of setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` on the command line when calling `cmake`.  That also worked for me.

So your problem might be due to CMake's caching of system requirement search results; maybe you ran `cmake` once without the right things installed or without the right environment configuration, and the lack of URDF support was cached then retrieved and used in your future runs, when you had everything configured correctly.

Whenever you change something (install or remove a library, or even change the way that you're invoking `cmake`), it's safest to delete everything in your `build` directory and start the build from scratch.  Then you're sure that previous search results aren't still in cache.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0